# Why the result of (/) function may also be Integral?

Tags: haskell

Consider:

```
> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

and

```
> :t (round 10 / 100)
(round 10 / 100) :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a
```

How could (/) result in Integral?

Comment: it's constrained to be **both** `Fractional` **and** `Integral` - `Integral` because you used `round :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b` and `Franctional` because of `(/)`

Comment: @Carsten I thought :t shows the type of the end result. Why does it consider some intermediate types?

Comment: it does - and of course it has to collect all the constraints for the *end-result* - see: `Fractional` alone would not be enough as `round 10` can only produce `Integral a`s - see: a `Fractional` does not have to be `Integral`

Comment: @JohnDoe: this _is_ the type of the end result. Only, it's a nonsensical type.

Comment: btw: *nonsensical*  because you will find it hard produce a value (by default the only `Fractional` instances are `Double` and `Float` both of which are *not* `Integral`) and of course `round 10` is rather useless in the first place

Comment: did you really try to write `:t round (10/100) :: Integral b => b` instead?

Comment: @Carsten sorry, I'm confused. Why does round (10/100) result in Integral? It uses Fractional while doing division, so why does the end type differ?

Comment: because the *end*-type here is the one from *round* which constraints it to be `Integral` - in the former case it's because of `(/)` which forces both arguments to have the same type (the left one was constrained to be `Integral` for the same reason as now) and adds an additional constraint of `Fractional` to it

Comment: If I define a function with the same code like this:
    `> let f x = round x / 100`
    `> :t f`
    `> f :: (Fractional a, Integral a, RealFrac a1) => a1 -> a`

and then call it
    `> f 10`

I get an exception: No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from a use of `it'

Is it what you meant by _nonsensical_ type?

Comment: yes - and you really want `let f x = round (x / 100)` - remember: function application has higher precedence than `(/)` - so you did `(round x) / 100` - with this you'll get `f 10 = 0`, `f 50 = 0`, `f 51 = 1`, ...

Comment: or maybe you want `let f x = (fromIntegral $ round x) / 100` which will give you `f 10 = 0.1` and `f 10.2 = 0.1`?

Comment: before you ask: this works because you get the `Integral` back into a `Num` by using `fromIntegral`

Comment: @Carsten Thank you, it makes more sense to me now. Can you add it as an answer please?

Comment: I would - but I think a real answer to the real question would basically involve a good explanation of the number-type-classes and their relation in Haskell

Comment: btw: you can play with this stuff if you use `:i` in GHCi - for example `:i Fractional` will give you all currently *known* instances of this class - and `:i round` will give you additional information (in which class it's defined, ...) as well - IMO this is the one thing beginners don't use enough (`:t` is often mentioned and used)

Comment: Thanks, did't know about `:i`.

Comment: @Carsten, the standard `Rational` type from `Data.Ratio` is a somewhat under-appreciated `Fractional` instance. I really like it when I'm using GHCi as a calculator or to play with series convergence since it takes away all the floating point stability concerns.

Comment: @dfeuer right ... indeed I use this way to seldom - thanks for reminding me :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are misreading the result type

```
result :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a
```

This type is a "contract" between the user of `result` and the implementor of `result`. Let's take it apart:

1. The *user* must first choose a type `a`
2. The *user* must then prove that the chosen `a` belongs to classes `Fractional` and `Integral`. Roughly, this means that the user has to provide a definition for the methods of such classes.
3. Finally, the *implementor* will provide a value of type `a`.

Part 2 is the crucial step. As we can see, the type of `result` does *not* promise to construct some value whose type is both a fractional and an integral. Quite the opposite: it *requires* that whoever wants to use that `result` value has to find such a type.

Concretely, this means that `result` is unusable. GHC does not raise a type error because it has no deep knowledge about the intended meaning of the type classes. Indeed, from a purely theoretical point of view, one could define a custom type and provide fractional/integral instances, e.g.

```
data A = A0 | A1 | A2

instance Num A where
   ... 
instance Fractional A where
   ...
instance Integral A where
   ...
```

with some weird implementation, such as performing fractional operations modulo 3, but not integral operations.

Anyway, since something like `A` could be defined, GHC can not reject the type above.